# How to feed only a string to Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have the following sample XML:

```
<all>
    <houses>
        <reg info='<root><h level="2" i="1"> something </h><root>' 
             other="test"
             something
        </reg>
    </houses>
</all>
```

I want to parse the XML provided in the `info` property of the `<reg>` tag, but I don't know how to feed the content of the `info` attribute to Nokogiri.

This is what I have now:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open-uri(mylink))
node = doc.xpath(//houses/reg)
puts node[0]['info'].class  #string
#content of info property as string. This is what I want to feed to nokogiri as xml
puts node[0]['info'].text
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Normally using the HTML parser to parse XML would be wrong, but in this case it helps because HTML parsing is more lenient. See my answer for Nokogiri's current behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the text of the info attribute, and use the GCI class to unescape the HTML. Then you can feed the string to `Nokogiri::HTML` and it will be parsed. Something like this.

```
require "nokogiri"
require "open-uri"
require "cgi"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open-uri("http://example.com/foo.xml"))
node = doc.xpath("//houses/reg")
info_string = CGI.unescapeHTML(node[0]['info'])
info_doc = Nokogiri::XML(info_string)
# Now you can have a Nokogiri document from that attribute.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = "<all>
    <houses>
        <reg info='<root><h level=\"2\" i=\"1\"> something </h><root>' 
             other=\"test\"
             something
        </reg>
    </houses>
</all>"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(xml)
node = doc.xpath('//houses/reg')
puts node[0]['info'].class  #string
puts node[0]['info']

inner_xml = node[0]['info']
inner_doc = Nokogiri::XML(inner_xml)
puts inner_doc.xpath('root/h')[0].text
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to note:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<all>
  <houses>
    <reg info='<root><h level="2" i="1"> something </h><root>' 
          other="test"
          something
    </reg>
  </houses>
</all>
EOT

doc.errors  # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: attributes construct error>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Couldn't find end of Start Tag reg line 3>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: root line 3 and reg>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: root line 3 and houses>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: houses line 2 and all>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag all line 1>]
doc.at('reg')['info'] # => ""
puts doc.to_xml

# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <all>
# >>   <houses>
# >>     <reg info=""/><root><h level="2" i="1"> something </h><root>' 
# >>           other="test"
# >>           something
# >>     </root>
# >>   </root>
# >> </houses>
# >> </all>
```

Parsing XML should normally use `Nokogiri::XML` as XML is a strict specification. This markup is malformed, and Nokogiri will correctly flag the errors, and, because it's malformed will attempt to fix it up and continue parsing.

Using `Nokogiri::HTML` loosens the reins and lets the parser be more lenient about what it sees; HTML is notoriously badly written so Nokogiri tries to be more accommodating:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<all>
  <houses>
    <reg info='<root><h level="2" i="1"> something </h><root>' 
          other="test"
          something
    </reg>
  </houses>
</all>
EOT

doc.errors  # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Tag all invalid>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Tag houses invalid>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: error parsing attribute name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Tag reg invalid>]
doc.at('reg')['info'] # => "<root><h level=\"2\" i=\"1\"> something </h><root>"
puts doc.to_xml


# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body>
# >> <all>
# >>   <houses>
# >>     <reg info='&lt;root&gt;&lt;h level="2" i="1"&gt; something &lt;/h&gt;&lt;root&gt;' other="test" something>
# >>   </reg></houses>
# >> </all>
# >> </body></html>
```

Notice how Nokogiri now:

- correctly HTML encoded the content of `info`
- correctly extracts and decodes the content for `info`.

I'm not sure if Nokogiri's behavior changed since the question was originally asked, but the current behavior in v.1.6.7.2 handles the decoding correctly without needing to use CGI.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to note:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<all>
  <houses>
    <reg info='<root><h level="2" i="1"> something </h><root>' 
          other="test"
          something
    </reg>
  </houses>
</all>
EOT

doc.errors  # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: attributes construct error>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Couldn't find end of Start Tag reg line 3>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: root line 3 and reg>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: root line 3 and houses>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: houses line 2 and all>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag all line 1>]
doc.at('reg')['info'] # => ""
puts doc.to_xml

# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <all>
# >>   <houses>
# >>     <reg info=""/><root><h level="2" i="1"> something </h><root>' 
# >>           other="test"
# >>           something
# >>     </root>
# >>   </root>
# >> </houses>
# >> </all>
```

Parsing XML should normally use `Nokogiri::XML` as XML is a strict specification. This markup is malformed, and Nokogiri will correctly flag the errors, and, because it's malformed will attempt to fix it up and continue parsing.

Using `Nokogiri::HTML` loosens the reins and lets the parser be more lenient about what it sees; HTML is notoriously badly written so Nokogiri tries to be more accommodating:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<all>
  <houses>
    <reg info='<root><h level="2" i="1"> something </h><root>' 
          other="test"
          something
    </reg>
  </houses>
</all>
EOT

doc.errors  # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Tag all invalid>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Tag houses invalid>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: error parsing attribute name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Tag reg invalid>]
doc.at('reg')['info'] # => "<root><h level=\"2\" i=\"1\"> something </h><root>"
puts doc.to_xml


# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body>
# >> <all>
# >>   <houses>
# >>     <reg info='&lt;root&gt;&lt;h level="2" i="1"&gt; something &lt;/h&gt;&lt;root&gt;' other="test" something>
# >>   </reg></houses>
# >> </all>
# >> </body></html>
```

Notice how Nokogiri now:

- correctly HTML encoded the content of `info`
- correctly extracts and decodes the content for `info`.
- has wrapped the XML in HTML `<html><body>` tags due to parsing the content as HTML.

To extract the fixed XML requires peeling back a couple layers:

```
puts doc.at('all').to_xml

# >> <all>
# >>   <houses>
# >>     <reg info="&lt;root&gt;&lt;h level=&quot;2&quot; i=&quot;1&quot;&gt; something &lt;/h&gt;&lt;root&gt;" other="test" something="">
# >>   </reg></houses>
# >> </all>
```

I'm not sure if Nokogiri's behavior changed since the question was originally asked, but the current behavior in v.1.6.7.2 handles the decoding correctly without needing to use CGI.

Answer (score -1):

`node[0].attr('info')` gives you the value of info attribute

Comment: That code will do nothing without parsing, and incorrect parsing will cause the `info` attribute to be mangled. Your answer needs to show how to make a workable solution.